# Does xlwings support "Wrap Text" property?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

Can I control the "Wrap Text" property of a cell using Python+xlwings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not implemented but I've opened a feature request [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/173). In the meantime, you can always work around by accessing the underlying COM object on Windows: `mysheet.range('A1').api.WrapText = True` or appscript object on Mac: `mysheet.range('A1').api.wrap_text.set(True)`.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap text the whole Workbook?

Answer (score 2):

For anybody like me who comes to this now and doesn't find these solutions are working, I found accessing the `pywin32` API directly with `work_sheet.range('A:A').api.WrapText = True` worked in Python 3.7 and xlwings 0.15.8 in Windows 7 and Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

For the newest xlwings version:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb1 = xw.Book('Book1.xlsm').sheets['Sheet1']

wb1.range('A1').value="It's currently not implemented but I've opened a feature request here. In the meantime, you can always work around by accessing the underlying COM object on Windows: "
wb1.range('A1').WrapText = True
```

Answer (score 0):

xlwings 0.19.5 this works:

```
    sht.range('A1').api.WrapText = True
```